# I have a list view that gets information from sql database and I have set OnItemLongClickListener

Tags: android, mysql, android-listview

```
public void ListDrwaer() {
     String outPut = "";
  List<Map<String, String>> dataList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

  try {
   JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
   JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("details");

   for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);    
        String desc = jsonChildNode.optString("saved_desc");
        String saved_pw = jsonChildNode.optString("saved_pw");
        String user_names = jsonChildNode.optString("user_names");
        number = jsonChildNode.optInt("num_saved");   

        outPut =number+" User name: "+user_names+"\nPassword: "+saved_pw+"\nDescription: "+desc+"\n";           
    dataList.add(createDataList("users", outPut));
   }

listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        String data =  (String) ((TextView)view).getText();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Edit data at Id\n"+number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        ConfirmBox(data, position);

        return false;
    }
});

  } catch (Exception e) {     
      //Go to add activity if no data to display
      startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Add.class).putExtra("data", "no"));   
  }

  SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, dataList,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    new String[] { "users" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
  listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

 }

private HashMap<String, String> createDataList(String name, String value) {
  HashMap<String, String> dataNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
  dataNo.put(name, value);
  return dataNo;
 }
```

This the whole thing now what I want is that when I long press on an item, I want to see a toast with the number of that item from the data base.

[image: list]

I have a field 'num_saved' in mysql database which is auto incremented whenever a user adds data to the database. When I retrieve data from the database every row has a unique value in field 'num_saved'

What i want is when long press on any item on list view see unique number `num_saved` toasted.
I have edited by and also added adapter code as requested by others.
[image: long press dialog]

[image: edit dialog]

Comment: I want the value in 'num_saved' field to be toasted when I long press an Item and the value in that field is different to every item since its auto incremented when a user add an entry in the database

Comment: Set the id of each item to textview tag and get it using getTag method

Comment: add code for adapter also

Comment: @MortezaSoleimani The id is a dynamic value from the database that I want for updating the entry for example when I want to edit it

Comment: @AkhilJain I have added the adapter as you said, please if you have any idea help me.

Comment: @stack4488 Please added screenshot or atleast tell, what data actually comes on `ListView` items, your code has lot of essential things missing.

Comment: @AkhilJain I cant post any image because my reputation is low.

Comment: share the imag url as link

Comment: @AkhilJain These are 3 image links from when user logs in and see his saved data, long press on one data in a list view then selects an option from the ones given respectively[link](http://ha-abu-neri.site11.com/pb/saved%20passwords.PNG)[link](http://ha-abu-neri.site11.com/pb/Long%20press%20option.PNG)[link](http://ha-abu-neri.site11.com/pb/edit%20option.PNG) Now my question is, when I want to update the table with respect to the item long pressed I need to use its id. Now how can I get that id from the selected item without showing it to the user as it is in the screen shots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will require lot of code to actually make it work, the right way as what i can say.

**REASON:** You are parsing the data JSON into a String, the `num_saved` is getting saved in `number` variable which is concatenated to `otuput`

```
  outPut =number+" User name: "+user_names+"\nPassword: "+saved_pw+"\nDescription: "+desc+"\n";
```

And in way, i cannot tell just by `String` that what ID number is that. The below code is **quick fix** for your problem as i see your code need lot more optimization and correction.

```
 String data =  (String) ((TextView)view).getText();
 int num=Integer.parseInt(data.subString(0,1)); //<= Here is your number
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Edit data at Id\n"+number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

By Using the `num` you can perform operation, show a dialog and do other necessary options